# State design pattern but avoiding singletons

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, state-pattern

This is getting little bit tricky. I am using state pattern in my application to manage states. I want to have a single instance of each state in my application but I do not want to make each state class as a singleton class. The other approach that is coming to my mind is writing a StateLocator class. StateLocator can be singleton and it can hold instances of all the states. Please guide me on whether StateLocator looks to be a good solution or are there any other solutions where I will still be able to have only one instance of the state and can potentially avoid singletons.

Any help is appreciated. e.g.

```
public interface TestState {

    public void onTest();  
    public void onApprove()

}

class StateA implements TestState {  
    public void onTest() {  
    }  
    public void onApprove() {  
    }  
}  

class StateB implements TestState {  
    public void onTest() {  
    }  
    public void onApprove() {  
    }  
}   

class StateLocator {  

    private StateA mStateA;   
    private StateB mStateB;  

    StateLocator() {  
        mStateA = new StateA();  
        mStateB = new StateB();  
   }  

   public TestState getState(int stateType) {

      if(stateType == 1) {
          return mStateA;
      } else {
         return mStateB;
      }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StateLocator, in the way you are using it, is the "Registry" pattern

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html

Knowing nothing about your design, this is a good way to avoid singletons.  The registry could be a singleton  ( doesn't have to be necessarily ).

Comment: The only bad part that I see here is StateLocator has to know all the possible states. Is there any way in which StateLocator can learn list of possible states itself ?

Comment: If you want your states to be discovered, you could use an observer pattern where you have a publish/subscribe system (like an event model). This would still require all states to be discovered and activated anyway. You could use reflection to discover those, and register them with the publish/subscribe model. That is probably overkill.

Comment: a Registry doesn't have to know all the states necessarily.   It might have an abstract notion of a collection of unique states by key.  so.... locator.RegisterState(stateA, 1);      or something

Comment: then use a StateBuilder to create your StateRegistry of states

Comment: Thanks Keith. RegisterState looks to be a good solution. Looks like I would need to hold a HashMap<int, TestState> in Locator.

Comment: Why do you want only a "single instance of each state"?  You seem to have set your self contractictory requirements.